# how to change iframe src attribute in typescript

Tags: javascript, video, iframe, youtube, ionic2

I am creating an ionic2 app. in this app i'm calling youtube API to fetch videos from my channel. when response came, it contains all video IDs of my channel. i want to make a list of videos, when user taps on any video, it will play on iframe created just above the list. my code so far looks like this.

```
            <ion-item *ngFor="let video of videosListItems"> 
                 <button ion-button (click)="playVideo($event, video)">{{video.snippet.title}}</button>
            </ion-item>
```

above code generates a list of videos. when user tap on any list item then `playVideo` function called.

```
playVideo(event, video){
  let playableUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+video.id.videoId;
  this.videoUrl = playableUrl;
}
```

`videoUrl` is data member of class in which `playVideo` function exists. now whenever `playVideo` function called then it updates the video URL to variable `this.videoUrl`. everything is good so far. but when i use this variable `videoUrl` in iframe. it does'nt load that video.

```
    <ion-card class="youtube">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" [src]="videoUrl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </ion-card>
```

how can i do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
playVideo(event, video){
      let playableUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+video.id.videoId;
      this.videoUrl = playableUrl;
     (<HTMLIFrameElement>document.getElementById('videoIframe')).src = this.videoUrl;
}
```

in html:

```
 <ion-card class="youtube">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" id="videoIframe" [src]="videoUrl" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </ion-card>
```